# Как увеличить иконку приложения

Tags: java, android

При сборке приложения через Android Studio,  иконка  меньше многих других  иконок приложении, как можно увеличить или что нужно настроить? Буду рад  ответам.

Answer (score 2):

Это значит, что вы создали иконку не руководствуясь [рекомендациями Google](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html)

Проще всего это можно исправить через Android Asset Studio (он встроен в Android Studio) - можно даже в онлайне - [см. сюда](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)

Comment: пробовал и через Android Asset Studio

Comment: тогда вам к гайдам - скорее всего вы/дизайнер сделали что-то не так. Например слишком большие паддинги задали